# Regular expression for time of a day

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for time of a particular day. It handles `7am` and `11:34pm` correctly. It should be able to identify the ill-formed times. Now I have tried writing a working regular expression for the problem.

**Regular Expression**`^(([0]?[0-9])|([1][0-2]))(\:[00-59]{2})?(am|pm){1}\b`

The problem is that in antemeridiem, the hour part varies from `1`(or `01`) to `12` but in postmeridiem it varies from `0`(or `00`) to `12`. I am not able to deduce the regex for this situation. Kindly help.

Comment: `[0-12]` matches only `0`, `1`, or `2`. Regular expressions match text, not numbers. Same for `[00-59]`, that matches `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, or `9`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have changed the expression.

Comment: I guess along with the rule @TimPietzcker explained, that ranges in character classes `[]` only match text (or characters), another rule that makes this very simple to remember is that ranges can **only** consist of two characters, other characters will be matched separately. For example `[0-9]` matches the characters *0* to *9* but because of the rule explained previously `[0-90]` could never match from *0* to *90*.

Comment: Also, I've never seen `0 pm`, and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), it's not correct.

Comment: What's the purpose of this ? Also what language are you gonna use ?

Comment: I am using `perl` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to start arguing what the 12-hour-system is supposed to be like, but just use your requirements as given/fixed:

> The problem is that in antemeridiem, the hour part varies from 1(or 01) to 12 but in postmeridiem it varies from 0(or 00) to 12. I am not able to deduce the regex for this situation. Kindly help.

Then, this regexp should work:

```
^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5][0-9])?am)|((0?[0-9]|1[012])(:[0-5][0-9])?pm))\b
```

See for yourself [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?33rs1).

Comment: Since I had a very heated conversation with one of the person over this. I apologise for the same. Now I realised that the question I asked is actually wrong. Still this is the answer to my "wrong" question.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do something like:

(my regex for am) | (my regex for pm)

As long as you have your parenthesis in the right place it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?(am|pm)$`

Answer (score 0):

This should match your requirements.

`^(([0]?[0-9])|([1][0-2])){1}(\:)?([0-5][0-9])?(am|pm){1}`

Also, you're trying to use regex to match numbers

> [00-59]

I don't think it works that way, you've to match strings, it would be better done as [0-5][0-9] instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find a good regex for this as well. I used a tool called Expresso and came up with the following expression for 12hr time matching:

```
((1{0,1}[012]{1})|[0-9]{1}){1}((:|\s)?[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1})?((a|p|A|P){1}(m|M){1})?
```

I tested against the following data:

```
12:00
12am
11111111PM
pm
11122am
13
00am
9a
```

and the expression came up with the following matches:

```
12:00
12am
1111
1111PM
1112
2am
1
3
0
0am
9
```

If you are validating data and compare matches to data length you can throw out the partial matches found from `11111111PM` and `11122am`. This works for me.